# Unable to create react app after uninstalling node

Tags: create-react-app, npx

I had uninstalled node and reinstalled node. However, after doing so and running the command `npx create-react-app my-app`, it fails.

node version `v17.2.0`
yarn version `3.1.1`
npm version `8.1.4`

This is what shows after I run `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
my-mac:test name$ npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in /Users/name/Desktop/test/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.3.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ babel-eslint@npm:10.1.0 is deprecated: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
➤ YN0061: │ chokidar@npm:2.1.8 is deprecated: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
➤ YN0061: │ fsevents@npm:1.2.13 is deprecated: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
➤ YN0061: │ rollup-plugin-babel@npm:4.4.0 is deprecated: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
➤ YN0061: │ @hapi/joi@npm:15.1.1 is deprecated: Switch to 'npm install joi'
➤ YN0061: │ svgo@npm:1.3.2 is deprecated: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
➤ YN0061: │ querystring@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
➤ YN0061: │ querystring@npm:0.2.0 is deprecated: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
➤ YN0061: │ uuid@npm:3.4.0 is deprecated: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
➤ YN0061: │ urix@npm:0.1.0 is deprecated: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
➤ YN0032: │ nan@npm:2.14.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ @hapi/bourne@npm:1.3.2 is deprecated: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
➤ YN0061: │ @hapi/topo@npm:3.1.6 is deprecated: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
➤ YN0061: │ sane@npm:4.1.0 is deprecated: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
➤ YN0061: │ resolve-url@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
➤ YN0061: │ flatten@npm:1.0.3 is deprecated: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
➤ YN0061: │ core-js@npm:2.6.12 is deprecated: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
➤ YN0061: │ @hapi/address@npm:2.1.4 is deprecated: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
➤ YN0061: │ @hapi/hoek@npm:8.5.1 is deprecated: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
➤ YN0061: │ request-promise-native@npm:1.0.9 is deprecated: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
➤ YN0032: │ evp_bytestokey@npm:1.0.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ request@npm:2.88.2 is deprecated: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
➤ YN0061: │ har-validator@npm:5.1.5 is deprecated: this library is no longer supported
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:11.0.4 doesn't provide typescript (p79ddf), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:11.0.4 doesn't provide webpack (p2af19), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 13s 254ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ yargs-parser@npm:13.1.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs-parser@npm:18.1.3 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:13.3.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:15.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yocto-queue@npm:0.1.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 16s 688ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:3.9.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.9.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.13#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.13&hash=18f3a7 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ ejs@npm:2.7.4 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:2.6.12 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 16s 310ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 47s 48ms
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/name/Desktop/test/my-app/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at [eval]:2:20
    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:38)
    at node:internal/process/execution:75:19
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:74:60) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/name/Desktop/test/my-app/[eval]' ]
}

Node.js v17.2.0

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with **package.json**, Install a **package.json** with the command `npm init`
Then you must see a `package.json` file in the directory after confirming `package.json`  try installing **react-scripts** with `npm install react-scripts`,
After successfull installation of `react-scripts` do a confirmation check again that under **package.json** you must have something like `script: react-script`. Then you are ready to go with creating your new react project

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```